# how to test hovering in WatiN

Tags: c#, .net, watin

I am trying to test hovering over an anchor that has a drop down. 
I am using this syntax:

```
Browser _currentBrowser = new IE();

_currentBrowser.Link(Find.ById("navigation-id")).MouseEnter();
```

The navigation-id exists, and ideally a `display:none ul` would change to `display:block`, but I feel that this `MouseEnter()` doesn't actually depict a hover effect. What should I be doing to represent a hover action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this...

```
Browser _currentBrowser = new IE();

Link myLink = _currentBrowser.Link(Find.ById("navigation-id"));
myLink.FireEvent("mouseover");
myLink.FireEvent("mousemove");
```

HTH!

Comment: BTW, if this throws an exception (can't remember if it was Firefox or IE), then use "onmouseover" instead